# Ace Editor trying to get themes from the wrong directory

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

When adding a theme to my Ace editor, it keeps using `-` instead of `/` in the directory, making it unrecognized.. Ive tried fixing this by editing the file system to match the incorrect one, but then the dependencies of the theme dont load correctly..

Picture:

[image]

Actual directory: `chrome-extension://njhpdepfakmoemiihkmhejlfedcohken/dependencies/js/ace/theme/ambiance.js`

Current Code:

```js
ace.config.set('basePath', 'dependencies/js/ace')
const aceEditor = ace.edit('editor')
aceEditor.setTheme('ambiance')
```

Comment: Where do you see a `-` in that path?

Comment: @LoganDevine in between theme and ambiance, it should be /ace/theme/ambiance.js

Comment: (now I see it, sorry!)